# How many type of Content-Type and Content-Encoding-Trafering in email and how to decode it?

Tags: c#, email, gmail, imap, email-client

I am using ImapX lib to recieve email from Gmail.

I get many type of Content-Type and Content-Encoding-Trafering of Body of email.
How to decode it?

Answer (score 1):

The MIME standards are documented in RFCs 2045 through 2048.  You probably don't want to read all of them, but you certainly should have a basic understanding of MIME before you attempt to process it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME is a good starting point.

The `Content-Transfer-Encoding` can have one of five distinct values; out of those, `7bit`, `8bit`, and `binary` do not need any decoding (they differ in what you can assume about character sets and line lengths; the difference between `8bit` and `binary` is that `8bit` is guaranteed to have lines of limited length; although you certainly see this violated in the wild sometimes).

For `quoted-printable` and `base64` you need decoding; but any reasonably modern programming language already has library functions for this.

The `Content-Type` hierarchy is basically unlimited.  There is a limited number of top-level types (`text`, `image`, `audio`, `application`, etc) and a standard set of subtypes (`text/plain`, `text/html`, etc) but more are being registered, and the standard doesn't require a type to be registered.  Anyway, these do not typically need decoding; they declare the type of the content, so that the recipient knows what to do with them.  The generic catch-all is `application/octet-stream` which basically means "here is a blob of data; hopefully the human recipient knows what to do with this" and for many types, there is no sensible default action other than to download to the local disk.  All general-purpose email clients will display `text/plain` directly to the user, unless the `Content-Disposition` requires otherwise, and most modern clients will display `text/html` and several other types inline.  But what you want to do with the content is first and foremost dictated by what kind of application you are coding.